# Is Resume of Fluid Simulation possible? Blender 3.1 Crashes Party Often

Tags: fluid-simulation

Sometimes fluid simulation completes sometimes it does not.
Example 250 out of 300 frames are found in the cache.
Estimated success rate 80%

Sometimes fluid simulation pause and resume works .. sometimes not.
Estimated success rate 75%

Often the particles system appears in 3D View on Blender launch after failure. If the Blender User changes the frame particle movement occurs. Yet Baking is not enabled via the Blender UI.
Forbidden Mesh fruit is not a pleasant experience.
VRAM info on Blender 0.9/6.0G
So some data is in the data cache.

Any suggestions before this Blender User is forced to delete partial bake and try once again to bake?

Thanks

Comment: This is speculation but you could try to go to preferences then system and increase cache limit. Lemme know if that works!

Answer (score 0):

If you load a project where you don't have the *Resume* button (as in, all it says is Bake All) and you know that your partial bake has had the *Is Resumable* option checked, then you can navigate to your cache folder and check the last rendered frame (they're all named `001`, `002`, etc.. `099`).

If your last frame is, say, `99`, modify the start frame of your simulation (not the project) to be frame `100`.

Hit *Bake All*. Assuming the cache has been loaded properly (i.e. you can see particles/mesh data on the viewport, Blender will resume simulating from that point forward.

Reminder that this only works if you've selected *Is Resumable* on your first time baking.